# Why does CEKDITOR show the actuall html code instead of rendering it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$("#About").ckeditor(function () { }, {
            htmlEncodeOutput: true,
            toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'FontSize', '-', 'Styles', 'Format']],
            height: 200
        });
```

**I am using CKEDITOR 3.6.4**

Here is the HTML output:

```
<textarea cols="20" id="About" name="About" rows="2" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;
    dasfdsa&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
</textarea>

<span id="cke_About" class="cke_skin_kama cke_2 cke_editor_About" dir="ltr" title="" lang="en" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_About_arialbl"><span id="cke_About_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">Rich Text Editor</span><span class="cke_browser_webkit" role="presentation"><span class="cke_wrapper cke_ltr" role="presentation"><table class="cke_editor" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tbody><tr role="presentation"><td id="cke_top_About" class="cke_top" role="presentation"><div class="cke_toolbox" role="group" aria-labelledby="cke_33" onmousedown="return false;"><span id="cke_33" class="cke_voice_label">Editor toolbars</span><span id="cke_34" class="cke_toolbar" role="toolbar"><span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span><span class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation"><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_35" class="cke_off cke_button_bold" "="" href="javascript:void('Bold')" title="Bold" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_35_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(49, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(50, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(51, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_35_label" class="cke_label">Bold</span></a></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_36" class="cke_off cke_button_italic" "="" href="javascript:void('Italic')" title="Italic" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_36_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(52, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(53, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(54, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_36_label" class="cke_label">Italic</span></a></span><span class="cke_separator" role="separator"></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_37" class="cke_off cke_button_numberedlist" "="" href="javascript:void('Insert/Remove Numbered List')" title="Insert/Remove Numbered List" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_37_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(55, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(56, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(57, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_37_label" class="cke_label">Insert/Remove Numbered List</span></a></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_38" class="cke_off cke_button_bulletedlist" "="" href="javascript:void('Insert/Remove Bulleted List')" title="Insert/Remove Bulleted List" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_38_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(58, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(59, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(60, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_38_label" class="cke_label">Insert/Remove Bulleted List</span></a></span><span class="cke_separator" role="separator"></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_39" class="cke_button_outdent cke_disabled" "="" href="javascript:void('Decrease Indent')" title="Decrease Indent" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_39_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(61, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(62, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(63, this); return false;" aria-disabled="true"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_39_label" class="cke_label">Decrease Indent</span></a></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_40" class="cke_off cke_button_indent" "="" href="javascript:void('Increase Indent')" title="Increase Indent" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_40_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(64, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(65, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(66, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_40_label" class="cke_label">Increase Indent</span></a></span><span class="cke_separator" role="separator"></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_41" class="cke_button_justifyleft cke_on" "="" href="javascript:void('Align Left')" title="Align Left" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_41_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(67, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(68, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(69, this); return false;" aria-pressed="true"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_41_label" class="cke_label">Align Left</span></a></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_42" class="cke_off cke_button_justifycenter" "="" href="javascript:void('Center')" title="Center" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_42_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(70, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(71, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(72, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_42_label" class="cke_label">Center</span></a></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_43" class="cke_off cke_button_justifyright" "="" href="javascript:void('Align Right')" title="Align Right" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_43_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(73, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(74, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(75, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_43_label" class="cke_label">Align Right</span></a></span><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_44" class="cke_off cke_button_justifyblock" "="" href="javascript:void('Justify')" title="Justify" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_44_label" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(76, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(77, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(78, this); return false;"><span class="cke_icon">&nbsp;</span><span id="cke_44_label" class="cke_label">Justify</span></a></span><span class="cke_separator" role="separator"></span></span><span class="cke_rcombo" role="presentation"><span id="cke_45" class="cke_fontSize cke_off" role="presentation"><span id="cke_45_label" class="cke_label">Size</span><a hidefocus="true" title="Font Size" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void('Size')" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_45_label" aria-describedby="cke_45_text" aria-haspopup="true" onkeydown="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( 80, event, this );" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(81, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(79, this); return false;"><span><span id="cke_45_text" class="cke_text cke_inline_label">Size</span></span><span class="cke_openbutton"><span class="cke_icon"></span></span></a></span></span><span class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation"><span class="cke_separator" role="separator"></span></span><span class="cke_rcombo" role="presentation"><span id="cke_46" class="cke_styles cke_off" role="presentation"><span id="cke_46_label" class="cke_label">Styles</span><a hidefocus="true" title="Formatting Styles" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void('Styles')" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_46_label" aria-describedby="cke_46_text" aria-haspopup="true" onkeydown="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( 83, event, this );" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(84, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(82, this); return false;"><span><span id="cke_46_text" class="cke_text cke_inline_label">Styles</span></span><span class="cke_openbutton"><span class="cke_icon"></span></span></a></span></span><span class="cke_rcombo" role="presentation"><span id="cke_47" class="cke_format cke_off" role="presentation"><span id="cke_47_label" class="cke_label">Format</span><a hidefocus="true" title="Paragraph Format" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void('Format')" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_47_label" aria-describedby="cke_47_text" aria-haspopup="true" onkeydown="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( 86, event, this );" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(87, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(85, this); return false;"><span><span id="cke_47_text" class="cke_text">Normal</span></span><span class="cke_openbutton"><span class="cke_icon"></span></span></a></span></span><span class="cke_toolbar_end"></span></span></div><a title="Collapse Toolbar" id="cke_48" tabindex="-1" class="cke_toolbox_collapser" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(88)"><span>▲</span></a></td></tr><tr role="presentation"><td id="cke_contents_About" class="cke_contents" style="height: 200px;" role="presentation"><span id="cke_52" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span><iframe style="width: 576px; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" aria-describedby="cke_52" title="Rich text editor, About" src="" tabindex="-1" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></td></tr><tr role="presentation"><td id="cke_bottom_About" class="cke_bottom" role="presentation"><div class="cke_resizer cke_resizer_ltr" title="Drag to resize" onmousedown="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(48, event)"></div><span id="cke_path_About_label" class="cke_voice_label">Elements path</span><div id="cke_path_About" class="cke_path" role="group" aria-labelledby="cke_path_About_label"><a id="cke_elementspath_32_1" href="javascript:void('body')" tabindex="-1" title="body element" hidefocus="true" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(46,1, event );" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(45,1); return false;" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_elementspath_32_1_label">body<span id="cke_elementspath_32_1_label" class="cke_label">body element</span></a><a id="cke_elementspath_32_0" href="javascript:void('p')" tabindex="-1" title="p element" hidefocus="true" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(46,0, event );" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(45,0); return false;" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_elementspath_32_0_label">p<span id="cke_elementspath_32_0_label" class="cke_label">p element</span></a><span class="cke_empty">&nbsp;</span></div></td></tr></tbody></table></span></span></span>
```

Comment: What is the input that you have give to that control ? I think that you have encode the tags of the html with HtmlEncode, or something similar.

Comment: @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.About)

Comment: How it's rendered on the html page ?

Comment: @Aristos I added the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **double encode** your html string and the `&lt;` have been done `&amp;lt;` and the results are the one you have. This is done probably because you have all ready the text html encoded, and you render on the page again using the htmlEncode.

Here is your code, with the correct encoding on the same text

http://jsfiddle.net/PX5Mg/1/

```
<textarea cols="20" id="About" name="About" rows="2" > 
    // double encoding !
    &amp;lt;p&amp;gt;dasfdsa&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&lt;br>

    // single encoding. I have left the > out of encoding, but you can encode that too
    &lt;strong>plus&lt;/strong>
    &lt;br>&lt;b>test&lt;/b>
</textarea>
```

Comment: at the load. i simple add a "test" which doesn't have any encoding, then I save it to the database. It is saying as &lt;p&gt;   Jason&lt;/p&gt;  instead of <p>Jason</p>. How do I fix that i suppose.

Comment: @jmogera when you save it to your database, save it unencoded. When you render it that - encode it once.